# How to write inner HTML on browser in VBA or VB 6.0

Tags: vba, dom, vb6

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ohtl As HTMLDocument
    Dim datasheet As Variant

    WebBrowser1.Navigate "google.com"

    Do While WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Set ohtl = WebBrowser1.Document
    datasheet = ohtl.body.innerHTML
End Sub
```

This code will save inner HTML into database but now I want to write inner HTML from database to browser.

I tried below code but it's not working.

```
Set ohtl = WebBrowser1.Document
ohtl.write = datasheet
```

Comment: Try `ohtl.body.innerHTML = "Hello World"` or add HTLM Elements to the Body

Comment: Not working @JeremyThompson

Comment: Write HTML to a text file and load it...

Comment: I have write HTML to a text but i don't no how to load it on browser..  @JeremyThompson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WebBrowser1.DocumentText = html;
```

Also you can `Navigate` to html files on your local harddrive.